# Need to make a program that will launch a different exe, but keep it hidden.

Tags: hidden, launch

I have an exe file. I want a seperate program to launch it, but keep it invisible.

Only the program that launches it should be visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

**Background Tasks**

Using background tasks you could launch the executable behind the scenes.

**Note:** If you do so, you still won't be able to prevent any indicators that that program normally sends to the user to alert them it's running (like a splash screen) from occurring.

If you wrote the code, or have access to the code, that became the executable, then you can use a background task in your program to run the code without having a separate executable.

It should be a simple matter to look up how to implement background tasks in the language you're writing in.